# Why is this linearly dependent when matrix is reduced and variables all equal 0?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This set of vectors: {(9,9,0),(2,0,1),(3,5,-4),(12,12,-1)} is said to be linearly dependent by multiple sources however I don't understand why. When I put the numbers into a matrix and reduce it I get :
1 0 0

0 1 0

0 0 1

0 0 0
,

so
x=0,
y=0,
z=0. I thought when the variables are all equal to zero the set is linearly independent, so I would like to know why the set is actually linearly dependent.

Comment: If you have more vectors than you do entries per vector, you have a linearly dependent set. Can you show your starting step?

Comment: If you set up $a(9, 9, 0) + b(2, 0, 1) + c(3, 5, -4) + d(12,12,-1) = (0, 0, 0)$ as per the definition of linear independence, then you'll find, after you create a system of $3$ linear equations from the $3$ coordinates, you'll be ending up with a $3 \times 4$ matrix (not including the augmented $0$ column) formed by putting the vectors in as **columns** not as rows. The solution to this system is what tells you the possible values of $a, b, c, d$, and it will reveal that there are more solutions than just $a = b = c =d = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

You reduced your problem to the problem to show that $(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)$ and $(0,0,0)$ are linearly dependent. The easy way to do this is to consider
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
= x \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
+ y \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
+ z \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
+ w \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$
and note that if $x=y=z = 0$, the equation holds for **any** value of $w$, which implies these 4 vectors are linearly dependent.

---

As a side note, if you have a set of vectors $V = \{v_i\}_{i=1}^m \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ with $m > n$, then $V$ will always be linearly dependent. (In your case, $n=3$ and $m=4$.) Easy way to see this is that it is possible with $n$ linearly independent vectors to generate any vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$, by taking the standard basis, so all vectors $v_i$ are generated as linear combinations of at most $n$ linearly independent vectors, and so cannot contain more than $n$ linearly independent vectors.